# How do I fix this to add a role mentioned in the command to the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding a custom discord bot for my server and I ran into this issue. I want to add a role to a user that is not predefined. IE: I want to be able to &addrole @user anyrole and add that role to a user. Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

//!addrole @andrew anyrole
if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return 
message.reply("Sorry pal, you can't do that.");
let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || 
message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
if(!rMember) return message.reply("Couldn't find that user, yo.");
let role = args.join(" ").slice(22);
if(!role) return message.reply("Specify a role!");
let gRole = message.guild.roles.find('name', any);
if(!gRole) return message.reply("Couldn't find that role.");

if(rMember.roles.has(gRole.id)) return message.reply("They already have 
that role.");
await(rMember.addRole(gRole.id));

try{
await rMember.send(`Congrats, you have been given the role 
${gRole.name}`)
}catch(e){
message.channel.send(`Congrats to <@${rMember.id}>, they have been given 
the role ${gRole.name}. We tried to DM them, but their DMs are locked.`)
}
}

module.exports.help = {
name: "addrole"
}
```

Comment: What result or error are you getting?

Comment: It continues to tell me the role could not be found.